# Disabling http methods in Jboss eap 5.x

Tags: jboss, http-method

I need to disable http methods like PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS and PROPFIND in my jboss eap 5.x server. Can you please tell me in which file to add the security constraints?

Comment: see if this post help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035666/how-to-disable-http-options-method-in-jboss

Comment: I have gone through this post but I am not too sure where to use RewriteValve in my server configuration and I have tried using the security constraints in my web.xml but it did not work. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the code below in web.xml file present in the following path of your server : \server\default\deployers\jbossweb.deployer

```
<security-constraint> 
    <display-name>excluded</display-name> 
    <web-resource-collection> 
    <web-resource-name>No Access</web-resource-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    <http-method>DELETE</http-method> 
    <http-method>PUT</http-method> 
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method> 
    <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    <http-method>TRACE</http-method> 
    <!--<http-method>ALLOW</http-method> -->
    </web-resource-collection> 
    <auth-constraint /> 
</security-constraint>
```